# Android: Changing activity when the google sign in is complete

Tags: android, kotlin

So I've just added google sign in to my android application and coded so when the login is successful the app will change activity.

However, it just seems to stick on the login activity and not move to the other activity.

If I then go off the app and back onto it, it has moved over to the activity...

Any ideas?

Heres my code fo the handle sign in:

```
private fun handleSignInResult(signInResult: GoogleSignInResult) {
    if(signInResult.isSuccess) {


        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, Pair.create(mMainLogoImage, "mainLogoTransition"))
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
        Toast.makeText(this, "Why isnt this working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to log in, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting success response?

Comment: Yeah, so the i have looked in a little further and the issues seems to be with using the transition from the activity to the next, if i remove the transition it works fine.

Comment: However, i test the animation just on a normal on click listener and it works fine too!

Comment: Follow activity transition docs.  It will work fine. Cheers!

Comment: The activity transition works fine if i just attach it to a onclicklistener, it doesnt work when i add it into the success though.

Comment: Lemme get something for ya

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the transition -

```
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle();
this.startActivity(intent,bundle);
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this... What is seeming to happen is that the activity is changing but for some reason the login activity is still staying on top of the new activity... (I can click the buttons on the new activity even though I can't see them and then the new activity will display)